# Is continue(keyword) not allowed inside the ternary operator in c++?

Tags: c++

Below is the code:-

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
   int n, c1=0, ans=0;
   cin>>n;
   string s;
   cin>>s;
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){//string always start with 0
     s.at(i)!='D'?++c1:--c1;//statement 1
     (c1!=0 && s.at(i)!='U')?continue:ans++;//statement 2

  }
  cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

statement 2 prompts an error:-

```
  solution.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
  solution.cc:10:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘continue’
     (c1!=0 && s.at(i)!='U')?continue:ans++;
                             ^~~~~~~~
  solution.cc:10:33: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘continue’
  solution.cc:10:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘continue’
```

But when I changed statement 2 a bit, then it prompts no error !

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){//string always start with 0
    s.at(i)!='D'?++c1:--c1;
    if(c1==0 && s.at(i)=='U')//statement 2
         ans++;
```

Does it reveals that continue or any other keyword are not allowed inside ternary syntax?  Will be much obliged for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. `continue` is a statement and only expressions are allowed inside ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

1. The ternary conditional expressions have the form

   `E1 ? E2 : E3`

   Where `E1, E2 and E3` must be expressions.
2. On the other hand, [`continue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) is a statement.

   > The `continue` statement causes a jump, as if by `goto` to the end of the loop body (**it may only appear within the loop body of for, range-for, while, and do-while loops**).

Taken together it would mean that `continue` cannot appear in a ternary conditional even if the conditional is part of one of the loops mentioned above.